# ListEntry class usage

Tags: c, winapi

```
  #include <windows.h>
  #include "stdafx.h"
  #include "List.h"

  typedef struct List_Node
  {
     LIST_ENTRY list;
     int val1;
  }LIST_NODE, *PLIST_NODE;

  int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
  {

     int i = 0;

     PLIST_NODE pNewnode;
     pNewnode = new LIST_NODE;


     LIST_ENTRY head;

     InitializeListHead(&head);

     for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
     {

         pNewnode = new LIST_NODE;
         pNewnode->val1 = i;
         InsertTailList(&head, &pNewnode->list);
         pNewnode = NULL;
     }

     while (!IsListEmpty(&head))
     {

         PLIST_ENTRY removeNode = RemoveHeadList(&head);

         PLIST_NODE mydatanode = (PLIST_NODE)CONTAINING_RECORD   
                                                  (removeNode,LIST_NODE,val1);

         printf("%d\n", mydatanode->val1);
     }


     return 0;
   }
```

with this code I am not getting the val1 data properly it gives me junk value?any thing wrong that I am doing?

Comment: Please read http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/, until you show that you have expended at least some effort to debug your own code -1.

Comment: yes I have tried debugging ... when I see the addresses the RemoveHeadList gives me the correct node address. but the problem is when I use the CONTAINING_RECORD macro the node address is not the one I inserted .

Comment: Good start. I assume you have read http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff563802%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read the [documentation for CONTAINING_RECORD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff542043%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The third parameter is described as:

> Field [in]
>
> The name of the field pointed to by Address and which is contained in a structure of type Type.

I suspect that your code:

```
PLIST_ENTRY removeNode = RemoveHeadList(&head);

PLIST_NODE mydatanode = (PLIST_NODE)CONTAINING_RECORD(removeNode,LIST_NODE,val1);
```

is incorrect. This is because the third parameter to `CONTAINING_RECORD` is not of the same type as the address that you are passing in. It doesn't make sense for it to be `val1` either. What it needs to do is figure out the address of the `LIST_NODE` from the address of the `LIST_ENTRY` that is contained in the `LIST_NODE`.

I think that using:

```
PLIST_ENTRY removeNode = RemoveHeadList(&head);

PLIST_NODE mydatanode = (PLIST_NODE)CONTAINING_RECORD(removeNode,LIST_NODE,list);
```

Should solve your problem.